# Write a Java program that reads in two floating-point numbers and tests whether they are the same up to three decimal places

Tags: java

Why my flow is going to else part of the if statement

public class Exercise6MatchDecimalValues {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner stream = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input floating point number: ");
        Double input1= stream.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Input another floating point number: ");
        Double input2 = stream.nextDouble();
        String input1StringDecimal = String.valueOf(input1).split("\\.")[1].substring(0, 3);   //To get the first 3 decimal values
        String input2StringDecimal= String.valueOf(input2).split("\\.")[1].substring(0, 3);  //To get the first 3 decimal values
        String input1StringWhole=String.valueOf(input1).split("\\.")[0];  //To get the whole value
        String input2StringWhole=String.valueOf(input2).split("\\.")[0]; // //To get the whole value
        System.out.println("input1StringWhole"+input1StringWhole);
        System.out.println("input1StringDecimal"+input1StringDecimal);
        System.out.println("input2StringWhole"+input2StringWhole);
        System.out.println("input2StringDecimal"+input2StringDecimal);

        if(input1StringDecimal == input2StringDecimal && input1StringWhole==input2StringWhole) {
            System.out.println("They are same");
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("They are different! ");
        }

    }
```

}

```
Input floating point number: 123.1234
```

Input another floating point number: 123.1234

input1StringWhole   123

input1StringDecimal   123

input2StringWhole   123

input2StringDecimal   123

They are different!

Comment: How about using `Float.parseFloat(input)`?

Comment: Debug: find out what the string is that you're trying to run `substring` on. You'll find it's less than 3 characters long.

Comment: I am trying to get the first three decimal values of two float numbers. Like input1 =123.1236 and input 2 = 123.1236   . The whole numbers and first three decimal numbers should be equal. When i am giving 34.123 and 34.123.It is showing proper output, but when i increase the number i am getting this error. Also When both first 3 decimals are same  i am not able to get inside the if statement, and the output is getting printed for else statement

Answer (score 1):

Float `23232.231231` is rounded to `23232.23`.

So if you convert that float to a string and take the portion after the decimal point, it is only two characters long, and `substring(0,3)` raises an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use double then it should work. You are giving double value to float hence it gets round off.